# Blazor validation not working when using Metadata class

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

I am using blazore Server side. Form validation is not working when using Metadata class. I am using scaffolding and my DB models are oftern automatically generated. If i modify the it wipes out all my Dataannotation validations.

Here is the class that i am using

```
public partial class RequestHelp
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string HelpFor { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfHelp { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime UTCDateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime UTCLastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}



[MetadataType(typeof(RequestHelpMetaData))]
public partial class RequestHelp
{

}
public class RequestHelpMetaData
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Who needs Help.")]
    public string HelpFor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select What kind of Help you are Requesting.")]
    public string TypeOfHelp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Currency.")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount Field is required")]
    [Range(1, 999999999999999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter positive number")]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Details about what you need help for.")]
    [StringLength(4000,MinimumLength=10, ErrorMessage = "Please eneter some details about the help you need")]
    public string Description { get; set; }


}
}
```

This is how i am using it in blazor.

```
<EditForm Model="@_requesForHelp" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />

                <ValidationSummary />
 </EditForm>
```

Comment: We can't tell from the code if both partial RequestHelp classes are in the same namespace. First thing to check.

Comment: It's already [noted on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20805)

Comment: yes, they both are in same namespace.
as noted in github; for me i don't get any error, compile or runtime